# Output words in speaker with arduino

Tags: arduino, embedded, hardware, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I want to generate voice in arduino using code. I can generate simple tones and music in arduino, but I need to output words like right, left, etc in arduino speaker. I found some methods using wav files but it requires external memory card reader. Is there a method to generate using only arduino and speaker?

Comment: There is an integrated circuit called the ChipCorder that was designed for applications such as digital telephone answering machines.  It integrates the audio codec and enough memory for minutes worth of audio.  Your microcontroller controls it via SPI.  There are versions that come in DIP packages.  It's not high quality audio but if you're opposed to adding memory and you only need a few minutes of playback then it's something to consider.  There is even an [arduino voice shield](http://www.spikenzielabs.com/SpikenzieLabs/VoiceShield.html) that uses a ChipCorder.

Answer (score 1):

Typical recorded sound (such as wav files) requires much larger amounts of memory than is a available on-chip on an Arduino.

It is possible to use an encoding and data rate that minimises the memory requirement - at the expense of audio quality.  For example generally acceptable quality speech-band audio can be obtained using non-linear (companded) 8-bit PCM at 3KHz sample rate, which if differentially decoded to 4 bit samples (so that each sample is not the PCM code, but the difference in level from the previous sample), then you can get about 1 second of audio in 1.5Kbytes.  You would have to do some off-line processing of the original audio to encode it in this manner before storing the resulting data in the Arduino flash memory.  You will also have to implement the necessary decode and linearisation.

Another possibility is to use *synthesised* rather then recorded speech.  This technique uses recorded *phonemes* (components of speech) rather than whole words, and you then build words from these components.  The results are generally somewhat robotic and unnatural (modern speech synthesis can in fact be very convincing, but not with the resources available on an Arduino - think 1980's *Speak-and-Spell*).

Although it can be rather efficient, phoneme speech synthesis requires different phoneme sets for different natural languages.  It is possible perhaps for a limited vocabulary perhaps to only encode the subset of phonemes actually used.

You can hear a recording of the kind of speech that can be generated by a simple phoneme speech generator at http://nsd.dyndns.org/speech/.  This page discusses a 1980's GI-SP0256 speech chip driven by an Arduino rather than speech generated *by* the Arduino, but it gives you an idea of what might be achieved - the GI-SP0256 managed with just 2Kb ROM - the Arduino could probably implement something similar directly.  The difficulty perhaps is in obtaining the necessary phoneme set.  You could possibly record your own and encode them as above.  Each word or phrase would then simply be a list of phonemes and delays to be output.

The [eSpeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/index.html) project might be a good place to start - it is probably too large for Arduino, and the whole text to speech translation unnecessary, but it converts text to phonemes, so you could do that part off-line (on a PC), then load the phonemes and the replay code to the Arduino.  It may still be too large of course.